# Should I delete an answer I posted too soon before knowing the question was a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, policy, etiquette, deleted-answers

I ninja-answered the question [Can one still deal Non-Lethal Damage if they trigger the Automatic Kill feature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/121419/can-one-still-deal-non-lethal-damage-if-they-trigger-the-automatic-kill-feature/121420#121420) with an answer right before it got closed due to being a duplicate, because I didn't check the close votes before hitting submit on my answer. In fact, I'm one of the people who voted for it to be closed, after answering and as soon as I realized what is effectively my mistake.

My answer is more or less identical to (or, at least, roughly as helpful as) the accepted answer on the related question. **Should I delete my answer or leave it?** And, to help me with learning decorum, please explain *why* the correct choice is the correct choice.

My guess is there's no reason to delete it, since the duplicate question acts as a sign-post and the unnecessary answer isn't really going to do any harm as part of that sign-post. However, I'm not sure if the goal of SE is to consolidate all answers to duplicate questions into a single question. Also I feel a little guilty about earning reputation for an answer I shouldn't have posted, even if I didn't know I shouldn't have posted it until right after I finished.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: hold tight and enjoy the irony coming your way... though I guess I should have waited for an answer to arrive here =D

Comment: Hah. Oof. Irony internalized.

Comment: Since "questions should be merged when they are 99% identical" (to https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6345/32426) and the question I ninja-answered is about the exact same rules interaction as its duplicate, I decided requesting a merge was sensible. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Okay, merged. That's the first time I've pulled that particular lever, so do let me know if anything looks off from your end. I'd say it's probably worth double-checking your answer for little bits of verbiage and agreement now that it's attached to a different question than you were reading when you wrote it.

Comment: Everything looks consistent on my end, so there's no problem with your lever-pulling. It looks like my wording is agnostic to the phrasing of either question, so all is good. Thanks!

Comment: Of course now I feel a bit guilty that I got the Necromancer badge in a fashion that was definitely not intended. Oh well. I think I've done my due diligence.

Comment: Oh, I don't know about that. You quickly wrote an answer that was better (as measured by voters) than a number of the existing ones. You've added to the good answers on an old question. I spent a lot of time in Catholic schools, and even I wouldn't feel guilty about that one =)

Comment: Okay, but I can feel guilty that I got the meta-Excavator badge for editing your "optino" typo and ruining the joke in the comments such that you had to revert it.

Comment: Okay, take your iota of guilt =)
(I did waffle for a while on reverting--you're obviously *correct*, but I have a fondness for that bit. IIRC it was one of the first times I interacted with a diamond mod and didn't get nervous/sweaty-palmed doing so.)

Comment: I'm supposed to be getting sweaty right now? My hands are currently dry-- I have so many things to learn. :(

Comment: *I got the Necromancer badge* Embrace the dark side ... you don't know the Power!  8^D